# Problem with tabular and npnoround

Tags: tables

When I compile the table below (I tried to edit the code so that it shows well on this site, but that too doesn't seem to work), I get very strange 
results:

- I want all numbers to be in the {3}{1} format
  but this is not the case for the number in the third and 6th column.
- How can I remove the large space between the first digit and the 
  opening parenthesis in the second and third column?
- I want a vertical line after the second and fourth column 
  (and no vertical line after the third).

This is the code:

```
\usepackage{numprint}
\npdecimalsign{.}
\nprounddigits{1}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|r| n{3}{1}  n{3}{1} l| n{3}{1} n{3}{1} l| n{3}{1} n{3}{1} l|}
\hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{e1}}&\multicolumn{2}{ c| }{\textbf{e2}} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{e3}}\\ 
  \hline
\textbf{e1}&&&1.712682&(0.9381452)&2.768738&(1.646461)\\
\textbf{e2}&0.5613594&(0.4711274)&&&1.959158&(1.001164)\\
\textbf{e3}&185.9336662&(2.1302318)&140.417800&(1.797353)&&\\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:tab1}
\caption{this data table}
\end{table}
\npnoround
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have additional `l`-columns, just replace `l|` by `|`. And using `n{1}{1}` instead of `n{3}{1}` solves the problem with the additional spaces after `(`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\npdecimalsign{.}
\nprounddigits{1}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|r| n{3}{1}  n{1}{1} | n{3}{1} n{1}{1} | n{3}{1} n{1}{1} |}
\hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{e1}}&\multicolumn{2}{ c| }{\textbf{e2}}
 &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{e3}}\\
  \hline
\textbf{e1}&&&1.712682&(0.9381452)&2.768738&(1.646461)\\
\textbf{e2}&0.5613594&(0.4711274)&&&1.959158&(1.001164)\\
\textbf{e3}&185.9336662&(2.1302318)&140.417800&(1.797353)&&\\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:tab1}
\caption{this data table}
\end{table}
\npnoround
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first request about the 
`n{3}{1}`

format, you have to omit the "l" specifier in the tabular definition line.

Regarding the other aspects, I came back when I have enough time.